# Bigquery Flatten table into Struct/Array with repeated values

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery with JSON string column that has repeated and nested values. I would like to convert into flat table but can have repeated values showing in nested form

JSON string

```
{
    "activity": "running",
    "device": "mobile",
    "dataset": [
        {
            "date": {
                "activity_date": "2023-03-13"
                
            },
            "value": {
                "heartrate": [
                    {
                        "max": 86,
                        "min": 30,
                        "name": "Normal"
                    },
                    {
                        "max": 121,
                        "min": 86,
                        "name": "high"
                    },
                    {
                        "max": 147,
                        "min": 121,
                        "name": "average"
                    },
                    {
                        "max": 220,
                        "min": 147,
                        "name": "Inrange"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It should look like this

```
activity    device  date          heartrate_max   heartrate_min heartrate_name
running     mobile  2023-03-13        86            30           normal
                                     121            86           high
                                     147            121          average
                                     220            147          Inrange
```

Please suggest how to do that, thanks

Unnest with join left

Comment: `$.dataset` array has only 1 element in it ?

Comment: When its a one day data, dataset array has [date, value.heartrate[max,min,name]]. When its per minute data json string has only multiple repeated values as[time,value] in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider below traditional approach in BigQuery using [*JSON*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) functions and [*UNNEST*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays).

```sql
-- sample table
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT """
    -- put your *json* here
  """ json
)

SELECT JSON_VALUE(json, '$.activity') activity,
       JSON_VALUE(json, '$.device') device,
       JSON_VALUE(dataset, '$.date.activity_date') date,
       (SELECT AS STRUCT
               ARRAY_AGG(JSON_VALUE(hr, '$.max') ORDER BY offset) heartrate_max,
               ARRAY_AGG(JSON_VALUE(hr, '$.min') ORDER BY offset) heartrate_min,
               ARRAY_AGG(JSON_VALUE(hr, '$.name') ORDER BY offset) heartrate_name
          FROM UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(dataset, '$.value.heartrate')) hr WITH offset
       ).*
  FROM sample_data, UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(json, '$.dataset')) dataset;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Jaytiger, its perfectly working or me.  I do have a followup question. This is just flattening of JSON record for one activity which is 'running' and for running there are heaps of records based on the date field. So query you have suggested above is working fine if I filter down records based on activity as running. However in the same BigQuery table I have several other records based on different activities like 'swimming', 'walking' etc. For each activity there are thousands of records and has different set of fields (nested and repeated) not same as running.

Comment: My question is if its possible to have all activities data in one column or do I need to create separate tables for each activity type (running, swimming, walking etc) as each activity has different number of columns once we flatten them out. Please suggest

Comment: Above query won't work if each activity has nested json objects with different schema since current flattened schema is only for one activity.  Depending on the analysis use case of this table, you might consider a nested and repeated stucture for each activity.  see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TVeG_dpGxk   Or, you may flatten a json object up to where it has a common field and store the remaining json object with different schema as it is in the shape of json string to defer the extraction for each activity.