# How to extract list inside list in BigQuery?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, list, google-bigquery

I have json with list inside list data as follows :

```
WITH sample_table_1 AS (
  SELECT '''{
   "id": 1,
   "data" : "[[\"Name\",\"Quantity\"],[\"Woody\",5],[\"Buzz\",42],[\"Potato\",20]]"
  }  
  ''' json
)

,sample_table_2 AS (
  SELECT '''{
    "id": 2,
   "data" : "[[\"Genre\",\"Name\",\"Sales\"],[\"Cartoon\",\"Sponge\",10],[\"Cartoon\",\"Patrick\",8],[\"Anime\",\"Naruto\",8]]"
  }  
  ''' json
)
```

My Expected Result is as follow :

| id | Name | Quantity | Genre | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Woody | 5 |  |  |
| 1 | Buzz | 42 |  |  |
| 1 | Potato | 20 |  |  |
| 2 | Sponge |  | Cartoon | 10 |
| 2 | Patrick |  | Cartoon | 8 |
| 2 | Naruto |  | Anime | 21 |

I'm thinking about for every first list inside list, then place it as title if not in title yet. However, I'm still new and confused to do that. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank You

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75780172/bigquery-flatten-table-into-struct-array-with-repeated-values/75780515#75780515) help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because in my case there is no key and value in each of my  data

Comment: Hi @KevinAdrianHalim, Json data is in key value format in BigQuery. For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data).